# How can i get local image to load in react while bringing the path from an object attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

i want to load an image locally stored

```
export const dataJeuxGrosLot = [
{
    id: 1,
    title: 'Jeu Spécial Noel',
    price: '$59.99',
    prize: '$3000.99',
    startDate: new Date(2023, 2, 20, 15, 30, 12), // (yyyy, mm, dd, hh, mm, ss)
    endDate: new Date(2023, 2, 30, 23, 59, 59), // (yyyy, mm, dd, hh, mm, ss)
    drawDate: new Date(2023, 3, 1, 12, 0, 0), // (yyyy, mm, dd, hh, mm, ss)
    linkImg:
        '../../images/halloween.jpg',
}]
```

i'm trying to load the image plus the other attribures like so:

```
{dataJeuxGrosLot.map(item => (
                    <div className="card">
                        <div className="card-top">
                            <img src={item.linkImg} alt={item.title}/>
                            <h1>{item.title}</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div className="card-bottom">
                            <h3>{item.price}</h3>
                            <h3>{item.startDate.toLocaleString()}</h3>
                            <span className="category">{item.prize}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                ))}
```

But image dosen't load and shows alt value any suggestions

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Add a error message. Also check if the image loads in new tab and check if the path exists.

Comment: The `../../` part is suspicious, hierarchy in your source folders doesn't necessarily apply to the location on the web side. What happens if you try without it? What's the path of the page in the address bar of the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you can do it like this:**

`dataJeuxGrosLot` array is part of a React component, you can render the images using the require function to load the images from their relative paths:

<img src={require(`${item.linkImg}`).default} alt={`item.title`} />

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what particular react framework or bundler you are using you'll likely have to import the images manually first and assign it to the `linkIMG` property of an item in your `dataJeuxGrosLot` array. Otherwise the image will not be included in the project once you build it and cannot be found.

```
import halloween from "../../images/halloween.jpg";

export const dataJeuxGrosLot = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Jeu Spécial Noel",
    price: "$59.99",
    prize: "$3000.99",
    startDate: new Date(2023, 2, 20, 15, 30, 12),
    endDate: new Date(2023, 2, 30, 23, 59, 59),
    drawDate: new Date(2023, 3, 1, 12, 0, 0),
    linkImg: halloween
  }
];
```